# Search for the name "Will" in a mysql full text search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I run a full text search on a "Name" index but i got ignored the name "Will" cause the word "will" is in the ignore list.

My database is hosted in a shared hosting, can't configure it. What's a possible solution for searching it correctly?

Comment: Try binary collation.

Answer (score 1):

As mysql documentation on [fulltext search stop word says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html):

> The stopword list is loaded and searched for full-text queries using
>   the server character set and collation (the values of the
>   character_set_server and collation_server system variables). False
>   hits or misses might occur for stopword lookups if the stopword file
>   or columns used for full-text indexing or searches have a character
>   set or collation different from character_set_server or
>   collation_server.
>
> **Case sensitivity of stopword lookups depends on the server collation.
>   For example, lookups are case insensitive if the collation is
>   latin1_swedish_ci, whereas lookups are case sensitive if the collation
>   is latin1_general_cs or latin1_bin.**

The server collation can bet set at session level dynamically (at least in v5.7). So, try to set it to a binary collation.